# How much over head in using secondary indexes in cassandra than Primary Indexes?

Tags: indexing, cassandra

How much over head in read & write operations in using secondary index?

How cassandra makes/stores the secondary Index?

What about manually create and maintain an extra index (table) than setting secondary indexes (ie, making 2 tables both using primary indexes, One for normal data storing and One for indexing)?

Answer (score 2):

The advantages of using secondary indexes is that the index is automatically maintained for you when you write to the table.

Under the covers, Cassandra essentially creates another whose rowkey in the index value and the row contents are the rowkey of the table being indexed.

[How Cassandra Stores Secondary Indexes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_index_internals.html)

The overhead depends on your data being indexed.

Here is a [good article on Secondary Indexes](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/indexes) and when and when not to use them.